# Simulating copy and paste on applications that don't allow it

Tags: keyboard, copy-paste

### Context

Some applications currently don't seem to allow copy and pasting.

For example I have an application that asks me to log in every time and it doesn't allow me to paste anything so I'm forced to type a very long and complicated password every time.

I don't think it's something they intentionally restrict but rather a limitation of the libraries they are using (maybe xQuartz?).

### What I've tried

I've tried cmd+C and cmd+V in the input area. I've also tried to right-click and click on "Paste" (which is highlighted) but that also yields nothing.

### Question

In any case, is there any way to simulate pasting on Mac OS X? Maybe by sending multiple key presses instead?

Comment: Cmd-V (paste) doesn't work?  That would be your "multiple key presses"

Comment: @Allan Nope, that doesn't work. Isn't that the standard "paste" shortcut?

Comment: It's helpful if you provide details like what you've tried already so we don't duplicate efforts and expand on the application - it's extremely difficult to solve an actual problem based on a hypothetical description.

Comment: Assuming you're copying from a 'regular' copiable location, try right click/paste in the troublesome area

Comment: @Allan I've updated the question.

Comment: Forget the hypothetical! What's the name of the application you're having an issue with, and where was it acquired?

Comment: @user3439894 Uhm. It's PokerStars and it was "aquired" from the official website.

Comment: Okay, I download an installed the app however it errors out with "Fatal Error Occurred Can't create window" and I can't click the check box "I am at least 18 ...", so I cannot test to see if AppleScript and SystemEvents keystroke command can be used to fill in what you're trying to paste. Sorry but I'm not going to troubleshoot the error. Good Luck.

Comment: [QuicKeys](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/) might be worth trying. It was a star at this type of task in its day - unfortunately, it hasn't been updated in years & idk how well it works on a modern OS.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was that the copied password (and the one with which I thought I registered) was longer than 20 characters. The input field on the application doesn't allow more than 20 characters long password and the website silently cuts them to 20.

By copying the first 20 characters of the password I was able to paste it in.